# coremltools cannot convert XGBoost classifier into coreML model

Tags: python, ios, xcode9, xgboost, coremltools

I have a question about coremltools.

I want to convert trained `xgboost` classifier model into `coreML` Model.

```
import coremltools
import xgboost as xgb


X, y = get_data()

xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
xib_model.train(X, y)
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert(xgb_model)
coremltools.save('my_model.mlmodel')
```

Error is as follows:

```
>>> coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert(xgb_model)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/karas/.pyenv/versions/anaconda2-4.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/xgboost/_tree.py", line 51, in convert
    return _MLModel(_convert_tree_ensemble(model, feature_names, target, force_32bit_float = force_32bit_float))
  File "/Users/karas/.pyenv/versions/anaconda2-4.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/xgboost/_tree_ensemble.py", line 143, in convert_tree_ensemble
    raise TypeError("Unexpected type. Expecting XGBoost model.")
TypeError: Unexpected type. Expecting XGBoost model.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert(xgb_model._Booster)
```

More about this converter: 
I just encountered this problem so I debug into `_tree_ensemble.py` and here is what I found:

The first parameter 'model' should be `_xgboost.core.Booster` or `_xgboost.XGBRegressor` or the **path of .json file** of the previous two data. Also, if you use the .json file, the second parameter `feature_names` must be provided.

Plus, according to [the python examples on github](https://github.com/tqchen/xgboost/tree/master/demo/guide-python), there is another way you can get a model:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import pickle
import xgboost as xgb

### simple example
# load file from text file, also binary buffer generated by xgboost
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('../data/agaricus.txt.train')
dtest = xgb.DMatrix('../data/agaricus.txt.test')

# specify parameters via map, definition are same as c++ version
param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}

# specify validations set to watch performance
watchlist = [(dtest, 'eval'), (dtrain, 'train')]
num_round = 2
booster = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)
```

Note the `booster` here is `_xgboost.core.Booster`.

Then you can do

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert(booster)
coreml_model.save('my_model.mlmodel')
```

Comment: I used your first approach, it works but now the problems is that it wants 100 different inputs while i expect it to get one feature vector. How can I handle it? Do you have any idea? it is like f00, f01, ... 
thank you